# Initialize variable based in two different namespace parameters

Tags: c#

I am trying to find a way to initialize a variable called model from two parameters, the two parameters belong to two different namespaces.

```cs
public void ManipulateSharedLines(XElement root, string cbcPrefix, 
                                  Simple.TaxInvoiceVM simpleModel, 
                                  Standard.TaxInvoiceVM standardModel)
{
    var model = simpleModel != null ? simpleModel : standardModel;
}
```

when I tried to use the way in the code:

> Error CS0173  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'Models.Simple.TaxInvoiceVM' and 'Models.Standard.TaxInvoiceVM'

both models contain the same properties,

```cs
public string ProfileID { get; set; }
public string ID { get; set; }
public string UUID { get; set; }
```

and they are used in the same functions.

Comment: Can you please share both `TaxInvoiceVM` types definitions?

Comment: The error is telling you that `simpleModel` and `standardModel` are two different types, so they can't be used interchangeably like that.  What specifically are you trying to accomplish and why?  What *compile-time* type should `model` be?

Comment: In addition to GuruStron, do you control both/either class? Can you edit them? What common functionalities do you need from them?

Comment: Did you intend to do something like: `IModelInterface model = simpleModel != null ? simpleModel : standardModel;`? (which could be `IModelInterface model = simpleModel ?? standardModel;`, btw)

Comment: In short -  if both types do not share some common base class or implement the same interface there is not much useful you can do. Obviously you can - `var model = simpleModel != null ? (object)simpleModel : standardModel;`

Comment: Regarding the update... Why do you need two different identical classes?  What are you actually trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: and also: do these two types share some common base-interface or -class, which you could use for your `model`-variable then?

Comment: Sounds like a deeper design-issue ....

Answer (score 3):

You can not assign two different types which dont implement/inherit the same base class or interface to the same variable (except for type `object` variables).

What you can do is:

1. Create an interface or base class which defines common functionality and/or properties for both types
2. Have both classes inherit/implement said base class/interface
3. Create a variable of that base class/interface and initialize it conditionally: `IModel model = simpleModel ?? standardModel;`

In my example i used the null coalescing (`??`) operator. It checks if the left side is null. if it is null, it used the right hand value instead. otherwise the left side value is assigned.